# GPL software, proprietary assets?

Tags: licensing, gpl, assets

I'm considering utilizing a few GPL libraries in an application I'm working on, the source code for which I'd of course make available and would be subject to the GPL also.

But a critical part of this application would be a large collection of bundled assets -- text, images, and so on -- that I do *not* want to make available without purchasing the application commercially. And while the assets do not include anything like code, they do include things like icons that would be used as interface elements which I've purchased under a commercial license that is not GPL-compatible.

So where is the line drawn in terms of what is or is not part of the derived product? Are *all* text/images/icons/etc separate from the "software", even if they're, say, built into the application package?

Comment: Have you read [Proprietary resources in GPLv3 project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9839/proprietary-resources-in-gplv3-project)?

Comment: Yep, that's it! Did a lot of searching but didn't try "resources" 